# As a now self-employed consultant, should I apply for work at a company I was previously let go from?

Tags: professionalism, job-search, applications, consulting

**Context**

A recruiter is advertising a role, and I can tell from the description that it is a previous employer of mine. This is an employer that "let me go" in the past.

It's a consultant position, so I would be going in on behalf on my own limited liability company. It would be paid each day that I work.

**The Role**

The role itself is within a department that I previously worked and know well. That department was my first position in that company, I moved around the company three times after that. I was there for around 5 years.

The specific role the recruiter is looking to fill is within 'xyz' area. I had some involvement with 'xyz' when I was working there, but at a junior level. Now, I am a freelancer consultant mostly specialising in 'xyz' and similar areas, having helped other clients improve their 'xyz' processes quite successfully.

**The problem:**

I was let go by this company following a year of absence due to serious health problems. I didn't appeal the termination at the time.

My health issues are now being successfully treated, and I am no longer affected by them to the extent that I am unable to work.

**My Dilemma**

Would it be unwise to submit my CV to the agency regarding this role, given my history with the company? They are looking for somebody available within 2 weeks, and I will be available by then.

I feel like I would be able to pick up the role quicker than any other candidate, (I worked with large chunks of it in the past). But, I feel a bit ridiculous even asking, maybe that's justified?

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's your past employer or are you assuming that?

Comment: I would definitely apply but be very open about what happened and make sure the recruiter is on board as well.

Comment: What was your performance and relationship like with the company before the company terminated your employment?

Answer (score 13):

> Would it be unwise to submit my CV to the agency regarding this role, given my history with the company?

I don't see a reason why not to send your CV and apply.

Furthermore, you *suspect* it *may* be your past employer, but you are not 100% sure about that...

Best case you land the job, and worst case you don't and have to keep job-hunting... but if you never submit your CV you will never know.

You were let go because, as you said, you were absent because of sickness and surely they needed someone to fill the role and be able to perform their business. It's not like you did something terrible or bridge-burning.

Comment: It's 100% the past employer. There is reference to a published piece of work that only exists within the company, it's definitely them.

I guess I am focusing on the time off being a terrible thing, despite the circumstances for it. Without the context of sickness, a paid year off is a terrible thing for a company to bear. (Aren't companies supposed to be psychopathic because that way they remain the most objective and can get the most value for their shareholders?).

Answer (score 10):

“Fired” sounds so negative. You were not fired, you were laid off. And not for a reason that any reasonable person would hold against you today.

No reason not to apply.

Comment: Well, OP might hold it against the company ;) I've worked at companies that would just assume you come back once you're healthy again - and stay in loose contact even if law-wise you'd be no longer employed. So being laid off and being forgotten could feel a bit cold and off-putting in comparison.
But you're right in that that's likely not what OP's asking about and that he should just apply if he in general would want the job.

Answer (score 1):

You make some good points. Yeah, there's a little bit of a negative history. On the other, you have insights that another candidate doesn't have.

If it's a short-term gig, it might be a good idea to apply. You won't be there long and they don't have time to spend working with someone to explain the company. If it's long term, they might be hesitant to restart a relationship that they chose to end. Or, you might simply decide to leave the past in the past and move on.

I think it depends on the scenario and the tone of how your relationship with them ended. They could let you go but were sad they had to do it, or they let you go and couldn't wait for you to get out.